# jQuery keyup event increase-"function" will set to 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, count, keyup

I've three input fields to "search" a JSON tree. If all three fields are filled and correct get the data from next JSON level.

I count up a number through the keyup-event to get next data of a JSON tree. But every time all three fields are filled the counter will reseted.

**HTML**

```
<h1>sein</h1>
<form>
    <input type="text" id=simple_present placeholder="simple present">
    <input type="text" id=simple_past placeholder="simple past">
    <input type="text" id=past_participle placeholder="past participle">
</form>
<div class="answer">Enter: be - was - been</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('input').on('keyup', function() {
    var count = 0;

    if (this.value === json.verbs.irregular[count++][this.id]) {
        $(this).prop('disabled', true).next().focus();
    }

    if ($('input:not(:disabled)').length === 0) {
        $('input').val('').prop('disabled', false).first().focus();
        $('h1').text(json.verbs.irregular[count++].infinitiv);
        alert(count);
    }
});
```

Perhaps the variable will set to 0 on each key-event? But I cant set it outside the `keyup`-event!

Here is a [demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/NnAMu/4/) of what I've done so far.

Just type:

1. be
2. was
3. been

Any ideas?

Comment: [Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/NnAMu/10/) and let me know if this is what u want.

Comment: What do the `count++` expressions represent? To me it seems you're incrementing `count` without a reason.

Comment: But now the `h1` will not changed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this

```
var count = 0, amount = json.verbs.irregular.length-1, current = 0,
inputs = $("#simple_present, #simple_past, #past_participle");

$(inputs).on('keyup', function() {
    if (this.value === json.verbs.irregular[count][this.id]) {
        $(this).prop('disabled', true).next().focus();
    }

    if ($('input:not(:disabled)').length === 0) {
        $('input').val('').prop('disabled', false).first().focus();
        if(current < amount) { 
            current++; count++; 
        }
        else {
            current=0; count=0; 
        }
        $('h1').text(json.verbs.irregular[current].infinitiv);
    }
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NnAMu/16/).

Comment: But the problem is, that the title will not changed now!

Comment: [Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/NnAMu/11/), it's working. What do you expect here?

Comment: **[This](http://jsfiddle.net/NnAMu/10/)** works well, but the title (`h1`) will not changed lik [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/NnAMu/)

Comment: `$('h1').text(json.verbs.irregular[count].infinitiv);` is `sein`, so, it's always `sein`.

Comment: `$('h1').text(json.verbs.irregular[count++].infinitiv);` sets the new title in my demonstration ;). But i think @fantactuka has done this job for now! But by the way: THANKS alot so far :-*

Comment: @yckart, just check the updated answer, [it's better](http://jsfiddle.net/NnAMu/16/).

Answer (score 0):

Got something working:

http://jsfiddle.net/fantactuka/56VBk/

Comment: Yeah! That's what i want... Thanks!

Comment: But, the input fields will not be disabled now... any ideas?